# Does radix sort work with numbers who have different number of digits?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I know that radix sort works by comparing the digits of the numbers. My question is, assume we have different numbers with different number of digits. Does radix sort work here? We can simply assume that, for example, if we are comparing two numbers, one with 3 digits and one with 6 digits, the first 3 digits of the smaller number is 0. But how about the implementation? How can we make the program assume that if there are not enough digits, then those digits are zero?

Thank you.

Comment: Left-side Zero-padding until all strings have the same length as the longest input string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to somehow add or simulate those nonexistent digits or sort the numbers in groups, each of which containing only numbers of the same length.

These 3 numbers

```
9912
 999
 123
```

can be transformed into

```
9912
0999
0123
```

and sorted using the regular radix sort or they can be sorted as 2 independent groups:

```
9912
```

and

```
 999
 123
```

The latter will give you (assuming ascending order)

```
 123
 999
```

and the former stays the same. Then you combine the sorted groups (from shorter numbers to longer numbers):

```
 123
 999
9912
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the number in an integer variable, then you can extract the digits like this (n = 0, 1, 2, ...):

```
digit = (number / radix ^ n) % radix
```